# Does it make sense that datetime encodes one-hot-vector like one-hot-encoding or something else like

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, word2vec, one-hot-encoding

I'm new to machine learning and deep learning. I've wanted to solve time series problem, which has data every single second. Plus, I've been doing research on word2vector and time series data lately. And one day, I've come up with an idea transforming sequence data like date time into one-hot-encoding?

```
    time
2017-11-01 00:00:01
2017-11-01 00:00:02
2017-11-01 00:00:03
2017-11-01 00:00:04
.
.
.
```

My idea has some limitations like below,

- too high dimensions for learning (1day = 60* 60 * 24 = 86400(s))
- unlimited time - time will be generated every moment even right now as well
- difference between seconds is too small to learn

I want you to determine what I'm saying above about limitations. Plus, I'd like you to give me some idea to develop time series data into one-hot-vector for machine learning and deep learning? + what do you think about this idea?

Comment: This question is better asked on [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Imran Thank you! I'll ask there

Comment: Why do you want to encode time? 
Are you predicting timestamp? Are you giving timestamp as input? Generally, time series data is input sequentially in order of timestamp

Comment: @UmangGupta yes, I'm trying to give timestamp as input too since i think that time also could be affected by not only the previous data but also the previous 'time' data.

Comment: I m not sure if that makes much sense. Basically, you are trying to imply that your model is non-stationary (i.e. it is different at different time? ) in that case, I doubt even feeding the timestamp can help.

Comment: I'd like to forecast data which is non-stationary and almost random like the stock price. In that case, how do I have to access to solve a problem?

Comment: You still hope that data depends on previous timestamp data and train auto-regression model (or some modification of it) in principle as far as I know. Look up some research in this domain, I am not very familiar

Answer (score 1):

No, one-hot encoding per second does not make sense. As you mentioned, the feature vector is way to high-dimensional. And worse: The feature vector is extremely sparse.

Instead, you can:

- Group by day: 365 features for one year.
- Add features like `is_weekday`, `is_workday`, `is_saturday`, `is_morning`, `is_afternoon`, ... - it depends on what is important in your problem!
- Maybe you can also add one feature with the Unix-time, but please do standardization (mean subtraction, division by expected range of values).

Comment: Hmm... then if you add the Unix-time with standardization, does a model determine the difference between time? As I mentioned, I'm worried that small difference makes learning confused.

Comment: plus, if I want to care about secondly-data, what features can I add? Things that you mentioned are also regarded but it's still quite a large scale for me. tell me if there's something wrong in my opinion

Comment: I can't give you a better answer without having a more concrete description of your problem. I doubt that the second matters

Comment: Let me ask a question from your suggestion. data which has features with a date, is_morning, is_weekday. For example, assume that today is 31st day of this year, morning and Wednesday. Should a vector be binary like [1, 0, ... 0, 1(morning), 1(weekdays) or values between 0~1 like [0.9, 0.1, ... , 1, 1]?

Comment: While I can see how `is_morining` could be continuous, I can't see that for `is_weekday`. What would be mapped to `is_weekday=0.9`?

Comment: My english is confusing you. So, basically, my question is which way is the right way to be transformed into a vector either [0, ... ,1(31st index), 1(morning), 1(weekday)]  or [0.02(1st index), 0.02(2nd index), ... 0.999(31st index), 1(morning), 1(weekday)].